# Cutting one mesh into a bunch o equal sized square meshes?

Tags: 3d-printing, knife-tool

I have a massive STL I want to print, and I want to print it at a very big scale so I need to cut it into equal sized square parts, as if I was using chicken wire to cut it. I'm also extremely new to blender so I might need to clarify things. Thanks for your time

Comment: Hello, maybe try with booleans? But you have other tools like Bissect

Comment: Try what with booleans, I barely know how to use blender at all, thank you though

Comment: maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/